# RDS Database read replica availability zone

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I have a master mysql database in the `us-west-1a` availability zone. When creating a read-replica, does it make any difference if I create it in zone `us-west-1a` or in `us-webst-1b` ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple trade offs.

- if in the same zone and that entire zone has an outage, then both
  your master and read- replica become unavailable. If you webserver is in just one zone, then this might not matter.
- if they are different zones, then you have some interzone data transfer costs. Anything written to the master needs to be transfered out of the zone, and there is a small cost associated with that.

Other than that, I don't think there is much to consider.

EDIT: it occurs to me this is probably the wrong forum for this topic.

Comment: thanks. Is the replication slower when going from 1a to 1b? We're seeing terrible replication lags (hours).

Comment: @DavidL replication would only lag by a small number of *milliseconds* across A/Z boundaries.  You have a problem unrelated to placement.